# Laravel's session variables going away

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-4, session-variables

I've implemented an OAuth 1.0a client in my laravel app. I want to store the temporary credentials and the access token I get in the user's Session.

As a POC, I've built my code using PHP native's session, using $_SESSION variable. Worked like a charm. But then, I wanted to move my code and use laravel's Session class instead. And this is how I realized that somehow laravel isn't saving my session data.

Here's the main part of the code concerned :

```
if (Input::get('release_name')) // ask for auth
    {
        $temporary_credentials = $server->getTemporaryCredentials();

        Session::put("temporary_credentials", serialize($temporary_credentials));
        $this->customLog(Session::get("temporary_credentials")); // this prints the string representation of my credentials

        return $server->authorize($temporary_credentials);
    }

    else if (Input::get('oauth_token') && Input::get('oauth_verifier')) // got back from provider
    {
        $this->customLog(Session::get("temporary_credentials"));
                    // here the Session::get returns null
    }
```

Any idea why my temporary_credentials got "nulled" at second step ?

Quick edit : I'm using 'File' driver

Thanks!

Comment: does `/app/storage/sessions` have the right permissions to read/write/execute files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in case anyone tries to implement the League Oauth V1 client within a laravel app, all you need to do to keep the Session working is to change this

```
header('Location: '.$url);
```

to this

```
return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::to($url);
```

Comment: Where is this change supposed to be made?